# Regex to rename/modify duplicate lines

Tags: regex, replace, duplicates, rename

I am seeking a single UNIX/Perl/PHP style regular expression to do the following with a list of text strings:

- Search for the first line that begins *with* the ‘#’ character
- Modify all strings with further occurrences of the search string but *without* the ‘#’ in the beginning so that the lines would begin with ‘#’ too. Such lines may have trailing text (but not necessarily do).

That must be done in one path.

E.g.:

```
some line
# some string
some line
some line
some line
some string some other string
some line
some line
some string
some line
some line
some line
some string some trailing text
some line
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rU1rM8/2)

So what I am seeking for is a regex that would match the line `# some string` and then add `#` in the beginning of the other lines that start with `some string`. The lines that would be matched and modified are,

- `some string some other string` -> `# some string some other string`
- `some string` -> `# some string`
- `some string some trailing text` -> `# some string some trailing text`

I had in mind doing something like `^(#?[^\r\n]+$)[\s\S]*(^\1[^\r\n]*$)+` for matching all such occurrences, but I need to split this to replace each individual occurrence...

Thanks.

Comment: What regex you have tried so far?

Comment: `^(#?[^\r\n]+$)([\s\S]*)(^\1[^\r\n]*$)+`

Answer (score 1):

Trying to write this as a single regex sounds like a recipe for unmaintainable code. I'd write it like this:

```
my $prefix;
while (<>) {
  # If we find a line that starts with #, then set $prefix
  if (/^# (.*)/) {
    $prefix = $1;
  }

  # If $prefix is defined and we find a line that starts with $prefix,
  # then prepend '#'
  if (defined $prefix and /^$prefix/) {
    $_ = "$prefix $_";
  }

  print;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However, this is not intended for the code, but as a step for a text editor macro, that's why there is a need to run it one-pass. If I could have used a cycle, I would have done that.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to mention restrictions like that when asking your question.

Comment: Dave, truly, thanks, yet I was asking for a regexp rather than code.

Comment: I understand that. But every regex engine is different. In order to get a useful answer, you need to tell us how the regex will be executed.

Comment: Okay, I heard you.

Answer (score 0):

A variable look behind would be great for this.
But most regex engines don't support that.  Only the fixed look behind.

However, if you can reverse that list of strings.
Then you could probably still use a positive lookahead on the reversed text.  And reverse the text back after replacement.

A very simplified example.

We start with the text:

```
z
# a
a y
a
x
```

Now we reverse the text:

```
x
a
y a
a #
z
```

Now we replace all (global, multiline)
`(\w+$)(?=[\s\S]+\1 ?#)`
by `\0 #`.

And we get:

```
x
a #
y a #
a #
z
```

Now reverse the result:

```
z
# a
# a y
# a
x
```

Answer (score 0):

FIND:

`(?-s)(?:.*\R)*?\K.*(some string).*(?s)(\R.*)\1`

REPLACE BY:

`\1\2 some other string`